# how do I fit a convex hull onto multiple curve in python?

Tags: python, convex-hull

I have some curves and I know the function of each curve. the combination of curves is as the following  image:

how can I find the convex hull that covers all diagrams? these curves are polynomial functions. does python have any function for this?
the function of each curve is as follows:

```
y = 0.00867 * x + -0.00001 * x^2 + 0.00000* x^3+ 24.08735
y = 0.00314 * x + -0.00000 * x^2 + 25.50681
y = 0.00092 * x + -0.00000 * x^2 + 28.09722
y = 0.00480 * x + -0.00000 * x^2 + 30.29156
y = 0.00255 * x + -0.00000 * x^2 + 36.37911
```

[image]

I need a curve like a blue curve that covers all other curves:
[image]

Comment: you ar looking to fit all curves with the same function? What do you mean with: 'a convex hull that cover all diagrams'? Secondly what do you mean by: 'these curves are polynomial degree 2 and 3 functions' you mean that a curve is former by 3 polynomns of order 2?

Comment: as I said in my question, I need to find a curve like the blue curve that covers all other curves under it and it is the best and nearest curve. I put the related function of each of the curves in the first diagram.

Comment: I do not see how the blue curve is the best that fit the other two red curves